# URL redirection from .php to .html 

Tags: .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [redirect *.php to *.html](https://serverfault.com/questions/418595/redirect-php-to-html)

My URL is `index-main.html` and it is redirecting to `index-main.php`, only `index-main.html` is showing on the address bar.  My .htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule index-main.html index-main.php
</IfModule>
```

But if I am calling `index-main.php` on the address bar, it is also working (the page displays), but the URL is not changing.

I want my URL to be `index-main.html` on the address bar.  If i type `index-main.php` in the address bar, it should redirect to `index-main.html`, the URL should change.

Comment: it doesn't really matter what you call it... it is displaying the same thing. is there a reason why you have the rewriterule on?

Answer (score -1):

You can rename your file:

```
mv index-main.php index-main.html
```

Then add to your `.htaccess`

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

And should work without rewrite_mod

Comment: this is a horrible way to do it. You will run every html page through php

Comment: first: but only in this vhost
second: is there any other html page if he uses php?