# How do I redirect .php pages to .html pages?

Tags: rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

I have a dynamic website, so all the pages are in `.php`, but I want to show an address ending in .html on address bar, such as: `my_domain_name/*.html`.

I do I make a rewrite rule such that, if someone hits any url ending with `.php` (like `my_domain/*.php`) it will redirect to an address ending in `.html`?

`htacess` file:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule index-main.html index-main.php
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: -1 for sounding like a whiny kid --> "pls help,". [SF] is for Professional System Administrators (et al) only. Please see our [FAQ] for details.

Comment: +1 for Chris S, -1 for the question, and if I could: **`-20`** for SMS-typing (which is a kind of "I don't want to make any effort")

Comment: this question is more for stackoverflawn thatn server fault i think...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a couple rewrite rules to do that:

```
#Redirects if a request for a php files comes in.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php.?$ $1.html [R=301,L]

#Rewrites requests for html files to find the php file on disk.
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this rewriterule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```